# How to get the name of the class in JQuery removeClass(function)?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find a way how to do it when I have a string of classes like that: `last_class;=next_class;^=mce;*=tiny;~=wysiwyg`. Where every class is separated with semicolon. It can contain a selector like =,^=,*= or ~=. My first idea was to use selectors to locate the elements which contains these classes because I expect that it is not possible to use these selectors directly in $.removeClass(). But the problem which I need to solve is how to refer to the result found by the selector (I mean the operator like *=,~=,^=). When I found the tag, **I need to get the name of the class** which I need to remove. How to do it? I know I could use the .removeClass( function ) syntax, but I have no idea what to write inside the function.

What I tried till now:

```
var selectors = "last_class;=next_class;^=mce;*=tiny;~wysiwyg"
selectors.split(';');
for ( var i = 0; i<selectors.length; i++ )
  {
      if ( selectors[i][1] == "=") // ..mce.., ..tiny.. , ..wysiwyg..
        {
        switch ( selectors[i][0])
          {
          case "^": // starts with
            var selector = 'class^="' + selectors[i].substring(2, 0) + '", '
          break;
          case "*": // contains
            var selector = 'class*="' + selectors[i].substring(2, 0) + '", '
          break;
          case "~": // contains word
            var selector = 'class~="' + selectors[i].substring(2, 0) + '", '
          break;
          }

        }
      else // last_class or next_class
        {
        var selector;
        if ( selectors[i][0] == "=") // next_class
          selector = selectors[i].substring(1, 0);
        selector = '."' + selectors[i].substring(1, 0) + '", '
        $.removeClass(selector);
        }
 }
```

Final goal is to remove all the classes which are in the list.

Edit:
Here is my second try. Not completed, but at this moment I cannot find out why when I return class_name the class is not removed from the element. I debugged it and found the class name is correct.

```
var selectors = "^=col;~=cl;*=-art-"["remove_classes"].split(';');
for ( var i = 0; i<selectors.length; i++ )
  {
  if ( selectors[i][1] == "=")
    {
    var search = selectors[i].substring(2, selectors[i].length );
    switch ( selectors[i][0])
      {
      case "^": // starts with
        var selector = '[class^="' + search + '"]'
        var regex = new RegExp( "^" + search + ".*", 'i');
        $(selector).removeClass(
          function(){
          for ( var word in this.className.split(" ") )
            {
            var class_name = this.className.match(regex);
            if (class_name)
              return class_name;
            }
          }
        )
      break;
      case "*": // contains
        var selector = '[class*="' + search + '"]'
      break;
      case "~": // contains word
        var selector = '[class~="' + search + '"]'
      break;
      }

    }
  else
    {
    var selector;
    if ( selectors[i][0] == "=")
      selector = selectors[i].substring(1, 0);
    selector = '."' + selectors[i].substring(1, 0) + '", '
    $.removeClass(selector);
    }
  }
```

Comment: OK, so correction of the code above as trincot remarked: `return class_name` must be corrected to `return class_name[0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not that straightforward. When you have `^=mce` you'll want to both of the following elements:

```
<div class="mce_edit other_class"></div>
<div class="other_class mce_edit"></div>
```

If you translate that selector to `[class^=mce]` and do `$('[class^=mce]')`, then you'll only match the first element. In fact, the selector to get both of them should be (space is intended in second part):

```
$('[class^=mce],[class*= mce]')
```

For the same reasons, the `~=` comparator is not that special, and corresponds to the `.classname` selector.

Here is a solution to both find the elements and then get the class name(s) from the found elements that need to be removed:

```
var selectors = 'last_class;=next_class;^=mce;*=tiny;~=wysiwyg';
selectors = selectors.replace(/;/g, '\n'); // to use convenient `m` modifier

var classExtractor = new RegExp(selectors
    .replace(/^(\~?=)?([\w-].*)/gm, ' $2(?![^ ])')
    .replace(/^\*=(.*)/gm, '[^ ]*$1[^ ]*')
    .replace(/^\^=(.*)/gm, ' $1[^ ]*')
    .replace(/^\$=(.*)/gm, '[^ ]*$1(?![^ ])')
    .replace(/\n/g, '|'), 'g');

var selectors = selectors
    .replace(/^(\~?=)?([\w-].*)/gm, '.$2')
    .replace(/^\*=(.*)/gm, '[class*=$1]')
    .replace(/^\^=(.*)/gm, '[class*= $1],[class^=$1]')
    .replace(/^\$=(.*)/gm, '[class*=$1 ],[class$=$1]')
    .replace(/\n/g, ',');

$(selectors).each(function (i, elem) {
    (' ' + this.className).match(classExtractor).forEach(function (match) {
        $(elem).removeClass(match);
    });
});
```

I left out the less-popular `|=` CSS comparator, but if you need that one as well, it should not be too hard to add the necessary code.

#### Remarks about your code

I did not look into your code in detail, but here are a few hints as to why `.removeClass()` fails:

- First of all, it would help you debug, if you would log (with `console.log()`) the final values you pass to `.removeClass()`. It would certainly help discover some of the reasons of the failures;
- `.match(regex)` returns an array, so that explains why the `^=` case fails in your second code version. You'd have to `return className[0];`. There could be other issues though, I did not test this further;
- You had built some selectors like `'class*="' + search + '"'` which should really be in square brackets, like: `'[class*="' + search + '"]'`.

Comment: Thank you much. You got my respect because this code is so professional and high level. It works really well. Anyway I didn't find out why my second code showen in my question did not work for single class names using only one operator ^=. I would be interested to know it. Even that I have matched the class_name I was not able to remove the class_name after return from anonymouse function.

Comment: You're welcome. I have added some remarks about your code at the end of my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no direct approach. You are in the right direction as far as handling things pattern by pattern. Here is a pseudo-code (avoiding RegEx as far as possible to make things easier):

```
// Create an array of class names.
var classes = $el.attr('class').split(/[\s]+/);

// Create an array of patterns.
var patterns = patterns.split(';');

// Go pattern by pattern!
for (var i in patterns) {

  var pattern = patterns[i];

  // Iterate over classes array
  for (var j in classes) {

    // If classes[j] matches your pattern, remove it from the classes array.
    var match = false;

    // Check pattern 1
    if (0 === pattern.indexOf('^=')) {
    }
    // Check pattern 2
    else if (0 === pattern.indexOf('*=')) {
    }
    // Check default case (if required)
    else {
      // Check for a match
    }

    // If a match is found, remove the element from the classes array.
    // Note: This is not as easy as delete classes[j] (:
    if (match) {

    }

  }

}

// Convert classes back to a string and assign it to the element.
$el.attr('class', classes.join(' '));
```

I hope it helps. The tricky part would be to match the patterns. The second tricky part would be to remove the items from the classes array.

Comment: I have it almost done. I have updated the question and added the code. The  problem however is that when I have found the class_name (which I have checked in debugger) so the class_name was not removed. I know this because if it would be removed, then it could not be possible to enter the same breakpoint when I have called the function again ...

Comment: If you have managed to match the class name, then the problem should be solved. I don't understand the problem after that. Try using console.log() to make sure you are removing the class names as expected (maybe you are losing a character or two during the matching process due to some teeny-weeny error).